# How to list all FTP-users?

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

I need to get all FTP-users, but I dont understand how to get (list) all FTP (vsftpd or proftpd) users, is there some solutions about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may configure vsftpd to serve local users but also virtual users. For that check your `/etc/vsftpd.conf`.

To list virtual users, check file in folder `/etc/pam.d/` starting with vsftpd, my is `vsftpd.virtual` but most probably you have once created this file.

```
cat cat /etc/pam.d/vsftpd.virtual
auth required pam_pwdfile.so pwdfile /etc/vsftpd.passwd
account required pam_permit.so
```

This means that your virtual users should be listed in file `/etc/vsftpd.passwd`

```
cat /etc/vsftpd.passwd
```

To list local users using vsftpd, check `/etc/vsftpd.conf` for line with something like

```
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.allowed_users
```

You can also make list of denied users, so it depends what you want this list for, be ware of that.

For more information check out `man vsftpd.conf` instead of `man vsftpd`.